# Why it show error when i open show model Not printing error after selecting some catogorie like gallery camera.. etc

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Sometime my code is running successfully but after sometime It give error Null check operator used on a null value Why?
Also Why it show error  when i open show model Not printing error after selecting some catogorie like gallery camera etc.
Mean it print error when i open showModel before slecting image.
When ever I try with if else condintion instead of try catch then it print no image found if(_image!=null){
//do something}
else{print("No image found");}

```
Future geturl()async{
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container( 
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.browse_gallery),
                title: Text("Pick image from gallery"),
                onTap: () async{
                  final gallery=await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery); 
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
                title: Text("Pick Image from camera"),
                onTap: () async{
                  final camera=await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                title: Text("Cancel"),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },

    );
  try{
    final reference=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("user3");
    final storage.Reference ref=await
    storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('upimages/${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString()}');
    final storage.UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(_image!.absolute);
    await Future.value(uploadTask);
    final  downurl=await ref.getDownloadURL();
    reference.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).update(
        {
          "imageurl":downurl.toString(),
        }
    ).then((value) {
      print("Update successfull");
    }).catchError((e){
     print(e);
  }
  catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

When i click on camera icon it show this error

```
  CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 70,
                              backgroundImage:_image!=null?FileImage(_image!.absolute) : NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["imageurl"]) as ImageProvider,
                            ),
                             InkWell(
                                 onTap: (){
  geturl();

                                 },
                                 child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo,size: 30,)),
```

Comment: `snapshot.data` might be coming up null

Comment: No this is not null this is only for showing image And it show image as I want .But I want to update image.